Inconsistent covariance estimates from sklearn.covariance.MinCovDet vs numpy.cov
I would expect that when considering a large sample from a bivariate Gaussian population, covariance estimates from sklearn.covariance.MinCovDet should be equivalent to those from numpy.cov ? Yet when I test this using the following code, I get systematically smaller variance estimates using MinCovDet. Why is that?
import numpy
import sklearn
import sklearn.covariance
from random import gauss

N = 10000

print(f'\n{"MinCovDet":>12}|{"MLE":>12}')
print(f'{"s_x":>6}{"s_y":>6}|{"s_x":>6}{"s_y":>6}\n')

for ___ in range(16):
    X = numpy.array([[gauss() for _ in range(N)] for __ in range(2)]).T
    RC = sklearn.covariance.MinCovDet(assume_centered = True).fit(X).covariance_
    C = numpy.cov(X.T)
    print(f'{RC[0,0]**.5:6.2f}{RC[1,1]**.5:6.2f}|{C[0,0]**.5:6.2f}{C[1,1]**.5:6.2f}')

print(f'\n[using sklearn v{sklearn.__version__}]')

Output:

   MinCovDet|         MLE
   s_x   s_y|   s_x   s_y

  0.98  0.94|  1.02  0.99
  0.95  0.94|  1.00  0.99
  0.95  0.95|  1.00  0.99
  0.94  0.96|  0.99  1.00
  0.95  0.95|  0.99  0.99
  0.96  0.95|  1.01  1.00
  0.94  0.96|  1.00  1.00
  0.96  0.95|  1.01  1.00
  0.94  0.95|  0.99  1.01
  0.95  0.93|  1.00  1.00
  0.94  0.96|  0.99  1.00
  0.95  0.97|  1.00  1.01
  0.95  0.95|  1.00  0.99
  0.96  0.95|  1.00  1.00
  0.95  0.95|  1.00  1.00
  0.96  0.94|  0.99  1.00

[using sklearn v1.5.0]



MinCovDet is a robust estimator which is capable to estimate correct value of the covariance in presence of many outliers. Basically MCD tries to guess what points are outliers and then estimate covariance on data without this outliers.
However as you may see from your test example it doesn't work well in datasets that doesn't contain outliers...
Also it is possible to get exact observations that were used to calculate the covariance. This could allow to check how well MCD manage the outliers.
X = numpy.array([[gauss() for _ in range(N)] for __ in range(2)]).T

fitter = sklearn.covariance.MinCovDet(assume_centered = True).fit(X)
    
# indexes that are used for estimating covariance;
support = fitter.support_
print (f"support size: {support.sum()}")

RC = fitter.covariance_  
C = numpy.cov(X[support].T)
print(f'{RC[0,0]**.5:6.2f}{RC[1,1]**.5:6.2f}|{C[0,0]**.5:6.2f}{C[1,1]**.5:6.2f}')

output show that now result from the numpy and MCD is the same:
MinCovDet|         MLE
s_x   s_y|   s_x   s_y
0.97  0.94|  0.97  0.94

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/covariance/plot_robust_vs_empirical_covariance.html#id4
